# Treat value as 0 if not update in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I want to update a number of current users group by language to prometheus every minutes.

I create a Gauge vector to do that.

At the first time, I report:

```
en: 10
th: 20
```

At the second time, I report:

```
en: 10
```

The problem is prometheus still keep old value of `th` as `20` if I don't update `th` value.

How can I make it treat the non-updated one to `0`?

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't export it. It will become "stale" and disappear after some time (5 minutes, by default).

However, most client libraries will not allow you to do that. Once you created a gauge, they will keep exporting it. So the alternative is you simply export `0` explicitly. I mean, based on your description, you actually do have 10 `en` users and zero `th` users the second time around, so just export that.